# Properties files best way of using them

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties

I am struggling with property files. In my application I am using two ways of property files: in spring and in my app directly.

In app I use a method to get property:

```
private String getHome() {

    String name = null;
    try {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        String propFname = "path.properties";
        InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFname);
        if (is == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("path.properties File Not found");
        }
        prop.load(is);
        name = prop.getProperty("HOME");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        log.error(e);
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e);
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return name;
}
```

and then in my class I use:

```
private static String home = new MailService().getHome();
```

But for JDBC connections etc I use Spring xml file with context:property-placeholder.

I wanted to make these two ways only one - the location of property files is also different, from above I have them located in /WEB-INF/classes/ and from Spring only in /WEB-INF/ which might be confusing.

About my questions:

1. Does it have any sense to unify these two ways, I mean are they both
   having their meanings or is it just better to use spring for both of
   them I am already using it?
2. In Spring I also found two ways of initializing the property, one
   using @Value annotation and second using @Autowiring bean. If I am
   correct they should both do the same function, is that just newer
   and older style or is there real difference between these two?
3. And last question: what I searched was different ways of saving property files to. Most common were /resources, /WEB-INF and /classes/config/. It that also differentiating through time or it is just on the programmer what he prefers? I didn't find direct answer to that.

Sorry if that question seems dummy but from searching different answers I got confused about the proper way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, please unify this - there is no reason to write your own code for accessing properties files since Spring provides this functionality either by injecting the values directly into the classes where they are needed with `@Value` or with an expression, e.g. `${home}` in your application-context XML.
2. Use `@Value` to inject values from property files. `@Autowired` serves the purpose of injecting bean not default values - it is not environment aware and you can't pass it an expression.
3. Put your property files in `src/main/resources`. This is [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) standard - Maven will deploy them to WEB-INF/classes and thus they are available on your classpath and easily accessible by your Spring application.

Comment: Thanks. I moved all property files under resources, make sense that way. And @Value seems to be working nicely and easily.

Answer (score 1):

1) Reading your question again, think i understood your question better now. You should have separate configuration files for Web/Database/Security/.. but you can keep one application property file.

I think you confused application property file which might contain your strategies, concurrency models, thread numbers etc, with configuration file used to setup ORM, Servlet mappings etc.

2) @Autowired is used for dependency injection of Beans and cannot be used for resolving values in property files. It is specialization of @Value.

3) My prefered way of saving the application property files is by allowing location be configurable via environement variable/ tomcat arugment.

You can do the following:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "file:${OTT_PROPS}")
@Profile("production")
public class ProductionConfiguration {

    // this must be static else spring does some odd stuff
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

}
```

Then provide location of property file as tomcat argument:

•   -DOTT_PROPS = "path_to_properties_file”

and use @Value to inject values from property file.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is nice way of making in generic. Probably don't need to use it in this app but good to know. About the beans - I actually made it working so it can be done but probably not the best way.